# How can I view messages in an Outbound MSMQ message queue?

Tags: messaging, nservicebus, msmq

I can inspect transactional inbound message queues (those usually under private)  either with computer management or using a tool like Cogin Queue Explorer.

However, inspecting **outgoing** queues is another matter.  I can see counts of messages, but can not drill in to message detail.

From time to time messages "seem" (I say seem, as I have read that the number of messages reported in an outgoing queue, are not necessarily a true reflection of messages in the queue) to get stuck in outgoing queues.

I would really like to know the content of these messages so that I can administer them (delete or replay for example).

Answer (score 0):

The one reason I can think of messages getting stuck in the outgoing queue is that the destination machine can not be reached (either network issue, the machine is down or other reasons).

Try a tool called [Cogin Queue Explorer](http://www.cogin.com/mq/) which is far better than built-in MSMQ snap-ins.

If machine availability turns out to be the reason, you probably are better off using NServiceBus DevOps tools (ServiceControl/[ServicePulse](https://particular.net/servicepulse)) to monitor endpoints status proactively (e.g. using Heartbeats).

In fact, [this sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/msmq/dlq-customcheck/) that was just released shows how to monitor Dead-letter queues with heartbeats.

Comment: Yeah queue explorer doesnt support drilling into outgoing  queues and messages contained therein.  It only provides a summary count .